# Schedule SSRS Report - Multiple times in weekday

Tags: reporting-services

How to schedule a SSRS report subscription to deliver report multiple times during weekday.

I need every 30 mins in a  weekday.

Answer (score 3):

Sure..

If you right click on the report in the folder view and select 'Subscribe'

Enter your email details and then in 'Subscription Processing Options' at the bottom, click 'Select Schedule'

[image: Processing Options]

Change the schedule details to report hourly and change the minutes to 30.

[image: SSRS Schedule]

This should work in your situation. You may not be able to do anything about the weekends though unless you use data-driven subcriptions and incoporate the day number into the query to not bring back any data on the weekends.

[Data Driven Subscriptions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx)

Something like:

```
--day isn't saturday or sunday
IF DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 7 AND DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 1

BEGIN

--Put your real query in here
SELECT 1 test1, 2 test2, 3 test3, 4 test4

END

ELSE

--Put a query that returns back zero results in here for the weekend
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 test1, 2 test2, 3 test3, 4 test4) data WHERE test4 != 4
```